# Is there a way to transpose data in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

This is my table:

```
pid     high    medium    low
1       10      8         6
2       20      16        12
3       10      6         4
```

I want store this data in another table in Hive with the following format:

```
pid      priority      value
1         high          10 
1         medium        8
1         low           6
2         high          20
2         medium        16
2         low           12
3         high          10
3         medium        6
3         low           4
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do this in Hive.  You just need to create a map and then explode said map.

**Query**:

```
CREATE TABLE db.new AS
SELECT pid, priority, value
FROM (
  SELECT pid
    , MAP('high', high, 'medium', medium, 'low', low) AS tmp
  FROM db.old ) x
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(tmp) explode_table AS priority, value
```

**Output**:

```
---------------------
pid  priority  value
---------------------
1    low       6
1    medium    8
1    high      10
2    low       12
2    medium    16
2    high      20
3    low       4
3    medium    6
3    high      10
```

Comment: This only answers half of his question, he wants the result set to appear in hive as another table.  Not sure if his requirements require it to be stored (which means we'd have to store the result set in HDFS and have another hive table read it), or if he can get away with just a view based on this select.

Comment: I think it answers about 99% of the question.  Storing data in a new table from a query is trivial.  Either way I edited.

Comment: Thank you. But how exactly to do the opposite, which is to transform long table to wide one?

Comment: @JamesWong See this answer I wrote on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-transpose-data-in-Hive/answer/John-Martinez-41)