# Transpose hive table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table in hive A which is like

```
 | ID   |   Code   |  Proc1   |   Proc2 | 
 | i    |    A     |   B      |   C     |   
 | i    |    1     |   2      |   3     |
```

I want my output to be :

```
 | i    |    A     |   1      |  
 | i    |    B     |   2      | 
 | i    |    C     |   3      |
```

I have read a lot of other articles and figure out that there is no direct way to do transpose in hive. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to transpose data in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436710/is-there-a-way-to-transpose-data-in-hive)

Comment: @gobrewers14 -- this is not what i am looking for. However i can try using map function and see if i can reach any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you are requesting.  I must say though, with any reasonable amount of rows this would be quite impractical to write.

**Query**:

```
SELECT id
  , new[0] AS col0
  , new[1] AS col1
FROM (
  SELECT id
    , COLLECT_LIST(code)  AS a
    , COLLECT_LIST(proc1) AS b
    , COLLECT_LIST(proc2) AS c
  FROM database.table
  GROUP BY id ) x
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(ARRAY(a, b, c)) exptbl AS new
```

**Output**:

```
id      col0    col1
i       A       1
i       B       2
i       C       3
```

Comment: I suppose that as an alternate to my answer, you could generate this code with a function to test what performs better. Note that this would also go beyond using just HQL. (With plain HQL you will be forced to hardcode as shown in this answer)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Hive without hardcoding. Assuming your hive database is in a typical ecosystem, I would recommend the following steps:

1. Load the data
2. Transpose the data with a scripting language like python (or R)
3. Create the target table with the relevant scripting language
4. Write the data to the target table